# How to disable the button until radio button is checked in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in the Ionic App and In that I have some list items with the radio button and at the bottom of the page, I have the checkout button. I want to disable the button until the user checked one of the item.

This is my **shipping.html:**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <ion-list radio-group>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let itm of shippingdetails">
            <ion-radio item-start value="{{itm.id}}"></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>
            <h2>{{itm.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{itm.mobile}}</p>
            <p>{{itm.state}}, {{itm.city}}</p>
            <p>{{itm.address}}</p>
            <p>Pincode: {{itm.pincode}}</p>
            </ion-label>
            <button ion-button outline item-end class="myedit22" (click)="editshipping(itm)">
              <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button outline item-end class="dele22" (click)="removeshipping(itm.id)">
              <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-12 style="text-align: right;">
        <button (click)="presentProfileModal()" class="myaddto22" ion-button square item-right>
          Add Address
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="single-footer" style="bottom: 51px; background-color: #fff;">

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="addCart">
        <button class="myaddto22" [disabled]="!value" full ion-button round="true">
          Make Payment
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-footer>
```

In this html, I am showing the items with the radio button and the checkout button at the bottom of the page but the problem is that, I am not able to disable the bottom button until the user checks the radio button.

[image]

In this, I am showing the items with the radio button and I have the button at the bottom. It will disable until the user select the item but the problem is that when the user select the item after that the button is not clickable.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to store the selected radio button in a model, and then set your disabled flag based on that.

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="yourSelectedRadioValue">
...
<button class="myaddto22" [disabled]="!yourSelectedRadioValue" full ion-button round="true">
  Make Payment
</button>
```

Comment: This could cause an error if the actual value of the yourSelectedRadioValue is "false" or falsy like null. Better to set a flag. But this would work in normal case

Comment: @DhananjaiPai. Can you please answer?

Comment: @Raghav the answer is correct, as long as the radio group has no option with value of `null` or `undefined` or `false`

Comment: @DhananjaiPai. Okay, Thank You.